# Is Xamarin a good crossplatform library for starting with Android and later moving to iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, xamarin, cross-platform

I am looking for a crossplatform library and as I do not have access to a Mac at the moment it complicates things a bit.

The plan is to start out with the Android version and then at a later point implement the iOS version when I get access to a Mac (I do have a Hackintosh but it is extremely slow and sometimes it can take several hours to get it to boot up correctly).
I have been looking at Xamarin as I usually work with .NET C#.
As far as I have understood Xamarin will share most business logic between platforms but the UI will have to be done separately. That sounds fine for my purpose I think? Having better performance in comparison to Phonegap is also very nice as the app might grow quite a bit in complexity over time.

Are there any limiting factors to this approach or are there another library that will be better suited for this? The goal is to do as much of the necessary work on Windows before moving the code to a Mac to finish up. In case that I wont be able to get my hands on a Mac I will have to use the Hackintosh so it would be extremely nice not having to do more coding than the absolute minimum on it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Xamarin.Forms http://xamarin.com/forms

You could share not only logic but also UI code if you won't use platform specific code (custom renderers, etc). The pros are you're doing a lot of things with a .NET ways (XAML, bindings, etc)

Short example:

```net
using Xamarin.Forms;

var profilePage = new ContentPage {
    Title = "Profile",
    Icon = "Profile.png",
    Content = new StackLayout {
        Spacing = 20, Padding = 50,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Children = {
            new Entry { Placeholder = "Username" },
            new Entry { Placeholder = "Password", IsPassword = true },
            new Button {
                Text = "Login",
                TextColor = Color.White,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("77D065") }}}
};

var settingsPage = new ContentPage {
    Title = "Settings",
    Icon = "Settings.png",
    (...)
};

var mainPage = new TabbedPage { Children = { profilePage, settingsPage } };
```

[image: App on every mobile platform]